# Оптимизация модели / контроллера Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток. Имеется такой метод добавления микроблога в контроллере:

```
/**
 * Написание микроблога
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function writeMicroblog(Request $request) {
    $model = new Microblog();
    $user = new User();

    $title = 'Написать микроблог';

    if ($request->has('write'))
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'sometimes|min:3|max:50',
            'text' => 'required|min:3|max:5000',
        ]);

        $model->writeMicroblog($request);
        $user->addValues(Auth::user()->id, 5, Config::get('ratings.mb.new')); // Прибавка баллов и рейтинга
        return redirect('/microblogs/' . DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId());
    }

    return view('microblogs/write', ['title' => $title]);
}
```

И, соответственно модель.

```
class Microblog extends Model {
    protected $table = 'microblogs';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    /**
     * Добавление микроблога
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function writeMicroblog(Request $request, $type = 'post')
    {
        $microblog = new Microblog();

        $microblog->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $microblog->title = $request->get('title');
        $microblog->text = $request->get('text');
        $microblog->type = $type;

        $microblog->save();
    }
}
```

Недавно узнал, что так делать вообще нельзя, т.е. `Request` в модели вообще не нужен, хотя я всё делал согласно документации. Если это действительно так, как можно улучшить код? Я так понимаю, в контроллере нужно вызывать `Microblog::create()`, но как тогда данные из `Request` передать в этот самый `create`?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите что написано о вставке данных в базу в [документации Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts)

У вас простой случай и все можно сделать в контроллере:

```
public function writeMicroblog(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $title = 'Написать микроблог';

    if ($request->has('write')) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'sometimes|min:3|max:50',
            'text' => 'required|min:3|max:5000',
        ]);

        $microblog = Microblog::create([
            'author_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'text' => $request->get('text'),
            'type' => 'post'

        ]);
        $microblog->save();

        $user->addValues(Auth::user()->id, 5, Config::get('ratings.mb.new')); // Прибавка баллов и рейтинга
        return redirect('/microblogs/' . $microblog->id);
    }

    return view('microblogs/write', ['title' => $title]);
}
```

так же можно вынести валидацию в [Form Request](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation).

Comment: По хорошему могли бы написать - вынести всю магию в переменные.

Comment: смысл в том чтобы показать как надо работать с моделью, а по хорошему я бы и валидацию по другому сделал. Не вижу смысла плодить бесполезные переменные

Comment: Видите, а я думаю по другому - если взялся переделывать и показывать как надо, то уж покажи до конца, как говорится. Переменный, ладно, но валидацию то уж подскажите. И меня чему-нибудь научите.

Comment: валидация в примере уместна, но при чтобы не писать валидаторы в контроллерах можно использовать [Form Request Validation] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, добавьте это в ответ, что бы я смог сменить голос.

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Я что-то наверное не понимаю, но чем отличается моя валидация от валидации в Form Request? И ещё, такой вопрос. Когда, в каких случаях запросы в БД лучше делать в модели, а когда в контроллере?

Comment: Смысл валидации в модели через правила в том, что вы пишете ее один раз для всей модели, которую можете использовать в разных контроллерах без копирование самой логики валидации в самих контроллерах (ну вот как то так, сори). Правила хорошего тона, на сколько я знаю, писать запросы к БД лучше в самой модели, даже маленькие, контроллер только контролирует/управляет, но это сугубо лично (я такое бывает в контроллерах заворачиваю). Главное что? Результат! (там ошибок куча, сори за французский)

Answer (score -1):

Согласно документации и код контроллера можно прямо в роутере написать.
Вот будет чуть по эстетичнее.

Контроллер:

```
/**
 * Написание микроблога
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function writeMicroblog(Request $request) {
    $model = new Microblog();
    $user = new User();

    $title = 'Написать микроблог';

    if ($request->has('write'))
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'sometimes|min:3|max:50',
            'text' => 'required|min:3|max:5000',
        ]);

        $model->writeMicroblog($data);
        $user->addValues(Auth::user()->id, 5, Config::get('ratings.mb.new')); // Прибавка баллов и рейтинга
        return redirect('/microblogs/' . DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId());
    }

    return view('microblogs/write', ['title' => $title]);
}
```

Модель:

```
class Microblog extends Model {

    protected $table = 'microblogs';
    protected $dates = [ 'created_at', 'updated_at' ];

    /**
     * Добавление микроблога
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function writeMicroblog( $data, $type = 'post' ) {

        $microblog = new Microblog();

        $microblog->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $microblog->title     = $data->get( 'title' );
        $microblog->text      = $data->get( 'text' );
        $microblog->type      = $type;

        $microblog->save();
    }
}
```

В этом месте: `$data = $request->all();`, только синтаксис уточните...

Comment: В модели создавать новый объект этой же модели который сам себя сохранит? это же Active Record, не надо так извращаться

Comment: Вы неверное не подумали, что я не знаком с фреймворком и мог не догадаться про `Microblog::create`. Ответил конкретно на вопрос ТС. Не правильно?

Comment: смысл не в Microblog::create, можно сделать сохранение как у вас, но только не в модели, а в контроллере

Comment: Вы хотите сделать ТТУК? По мне дак и так нормально. Можно было конечно и так: `$microblog = new static();`, но у ТС вопрос был в другом.

Comment: В простом сохранении данных нет логики, поэтому нет необходимости выделять для этого отдельные методы в модели и в контроллере такой код уместен. Если же у вас много логики в контроллере - нужно выделить еще один слой в приложении, например в виде сервисов.